# Mongo using (much) too much space

Tags: mongodb, diskspace

**UPDATE**

I at first had some small databases, but I have since I dropped all databases in a (fruitless) effort to fix this.

`show dbs` shows

```
config  0.046875GB
```

But `find /var/lib/mongo -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 du -b` shows

```
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/journal/j._3
88  /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/journal/lsn
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/journal/prealloc.1
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/journal/prealloc.2
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.0
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.1
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.2
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.3
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.4
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.5
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.6
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/local.ns
5   /var/lib/mongo/a1/data/mongod.lock
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/journal/j._1
88  /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/journal/lsn
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/journal/prealloc.1
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/journal/prealloc.2
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.0
33554432    /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.1
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.2
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.3
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.4
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.5
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.6
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.7
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.8
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/local.ns
5   /var/lib/mongo/a2/data/mongod.lock
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/journal/j._4
88  /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/journal/lsn
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/journal/prealloc.1
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/journal/prealloc.2
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.0
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.1
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.2
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.3
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.4
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.5
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.6
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/local.ns
5   /var/lib/mongo/b1/data/mongod.lock
16384   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/journal/j._1
88  /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/journal/lsn
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.0
33554432    /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.1
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.2
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.3
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.4
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.5
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.6
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.7
536608768   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.8
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/local.ns
5   /var/lib/mongo/b2/data/mongod.lock
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/config/data/config.0
33554432    /var/lib/mongo/config/data/config.1
16777216    /var/lib/mongo/config/data/config.ns
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/config/data/journal/j._0
88  /var/lib/mongo/config/data/journal/lsn
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/config/data/journal/prealloc.1
134217728   /var/lib/mongo/config/data/journal/prealloc.2
5   /var/lib/mongo/config/data/mongod.lock
```

**Thats over 17GB for no data!** Sheesh.

Why is Mongo taking so much space, and how can I reduce it?

Comment: Seems that most of the space is taken by a `local` database. Is it a part of replica set?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I apologize, but I don't know what that means. I know little about Mongo.

Comment: Are you running multiple instances of mongo on the same machine?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, no.

Comment: do you often delete documents? your databases may be fragmented. you can try using `repair` or `compact`.

Comment: @shx2, I tried that; see updated answer.

Comment: That's weird then - you seem to have 4 copies of everything (a1,a2,b1,b2) - it looks like (at least at some point) this machine was setup to be a sharded replica set (in development you can put all the shards on one machine). The local database is only used for replication afaik: it's used to store the oplog (mongo's equivalent of mysql's bin log) and mongo will preallocate a big chunk of space for it. All in all this doesn't look much like a normal mongo install

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I did not do the initial install. I believe it was set up to be sharded on a single dev machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What are all these files?

It looks like whoever did the initial install in your environment created a [sharded cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/), which was probably two shards each backed by two data-bearing nodes in a [replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/). They chose to create subdirectories for each node under a common path of `/var/lib/mongo/`.

Based on the subdirectory names, I would guess that `a1` and `a2` were a replica set for shard `a` and `b1` and `b1` were part of a replica set for shard `b`. If you are curious, you could probably confirm the former configuration by inspecting the [`config` database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/config-database/) which still exists.

In a case, in a replica set each data-bearing node has a preallocated [`oplog` (operation log)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) which is used for replication. The oplog is stored in the `oplog.rs` collection in the `local` database.

By default the [oplog size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) is 5% of free disk space (at least on a 64-bit Linux system) which is why these are taking up a good chunk of disk despite having an "empty" database.

#### How can I safely clean up this data directory?

If you are only running a single MongoDB instance, by default it will ignore extra subdirectories and their contents. This is why you still have extra disk usage - you've dropped all the databases that your `mongod` knows about.

If you want to "reset" *all* the data and start fresh you should:

- stop your running `mongod` instance, eg: `sudo service mongod stop`
- Note: if you want to be extra certain there are no lingering `mongod` processes from the previous sharded installation, you could also run: `killall mongod; killall mongos`
- change to the data directory: `cd /var/lib/mongo/`
- **make sure you are in the expected directory**: `pwd`
- remove all files: `rm -r *`
- restart `mongod`, eg: `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: Perhaps they were 5% of free space at one time, but that is certainly not the case anymore.

Comment: Indeed, the oplog preallocation is based on the free space at the time a replica node is initialised. Once allocated, the oplog size does not change (unless you manually [change the size of the oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/)).